# How to fix "Undefined Variable" in node-sass?

Tags: css, npm, sass, compiler-errors

I think that there is a bug with node-sass...

I've:
- app.scss
- variables.scss
- style.scss

*app.scss*

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'style';
```

*variables.scss*

```
$green: #38c172;
```

*style.scss*

```
button{
    background-color: $green;
    }
```

It works fine, because in my file *app.css* I have:

```
button{
    background-color: #38c172;
    }
```

But I have always this error... why!?? I hate this!

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I've fixed that!
All the files must be renamed with an "_" to the beginning exept for app.scss

Answer (score 2):

It says that error is coming from line 42 in header.scss file.

border-bottom: 3px solid $green; is causing it.
Check if you imported variables properly for header.scss file.

Comment: It’s the same... I did just a little example but the order of the files is this... So I don’t know ...

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of header.scss? 
Or perhaps variables file?

Comment: sure, [link](https://jsfiddle.net/r3ecb0mq/) 
Here you can find:
-app.scss
-const.scss
-header.scss

Comment: Okay, so header.scss throws the error. And that is the only place you actually use variable. 
I believe that your import is not right. Could you instead use relative path? 
So something like -> @import './src/scss/const.scss'? 
It could be the path..
Or try creating another file (test.scss) and try using variable there, see what you get, if variable is undefined, than it is the pathing problem.